# Negative reputation changes not shown on summary tab of profile

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

The reputation graph is showing the correct value and the reputation tab also lists the negative change. However the list under the graph on the summary tab only seems to show positive changes. Is it [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)? At first I thought it might be to hide what I have downvoted on, but apparently this entire reputation graph is not shown in the public profile.

**Screenshot of reputation tab**:
[image: reputation tab]

---

**Screenshot of summary tab**:
[image: summary tab]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is by design because the reputation tab is a summary of rep changes that happen *to* you, not rep changes that happen *by* you.

Comment: It might be the usual "encourage users by showing a lot of green to them" concept.